# Error in my Javascript program to calculate Average marks of a student

Tags: javascript, html

This is my simple javascript program to calculate.. When i call input() function or A() function inside document.script onclick its showing A is not defined and input is not defined.. Can someone say what error it is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="input()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var name=new Array(5);
        var roll=new Array(5);
        var m1=new Array(5);
        var m2=new Array(5);
        var m3=new Array(5);
        var total=new Array(5);
        var avg=new Array(5);
        var i=1;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function  A()
        {
            m1[i]=parseInt(document.getElementById('m1').value);
            m2[i]=parseInt(document.getElementById('m2').value);
            m3[i]=parseInt(document.getElementById('m3').value);
            avg[i]=(m1[i]+m2[i]+m3[i])/3;
            total[i]=(m1[i]+m2[i]+m3[i]);
            var mark="Avg="+avg[i]+"<br> Total="+total[i];
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=mark;
            i++;
        }
    </script>      
    <script>   
        function input()
        {
            document.write(" <form name='stud'> ");
            document.write(" Enter Name  :<input type='text' name='name'><br>");
            document.write(" Enter RollNo:<input type='number' name='no'><br>");
            document.write(" Enter mark 1:<input type='number' name='m1' id='m1'><br>");
            document.write(" Enter mark 2:<input type='number' name='m2' id='m2'><br>");
            document.write(" Enter mark 3:<input type='number' name='m3' id='m3'><br>");

            document.write("<input type='button' value='calculate' onclick='A();'>");
            document.write(" <br>");

            document.write("<input type='button' value='Enter For Next Student' onclick='input()'>");
            document.write(" <br><p id='1'></p>   ");  
        }
    </script>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.write` obliterates your document. This will remove your script code and everything else. Why are you using document.write?

Comment: @LeeTaylor : Not exactly, it depends on how you use it. If you use it before the page loads and in-place it's fine to use. Although using document.write after page loads it overwrites.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek See `onload="input()"`

Comment: @LeeTaylor Yes I know, I'm talking about just in general. Yes in his case it does overwrite. You sound like you implied that document.write always overwrites. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek No worries!

Comment: Then how to use my html tags inside javascript????

Comment: @FeroozKhan Why not just write regular HTML without using javascipt's document.write?

Comment: i need to call the same fuction many times for getting marks for certain number of students..

Comment: You can use 'document.write'. Just use it as your writing HTML.      `<body>....<script>document.write(..);</script>....</body>` For example: http://jsfiddle.net/5zBg6/

Comment: But how to create a function using this method.. So that i can use the form repeatedly

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body >
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var name=new Array(5);
    var roll=new Array(5);
    var m1=new Array(5);
    var m2=new Array(5);
    var m3=new Array(5);
    var total=new Array(5);
    var avg=new Array(5);
    var i=1;

    function  A()
    {
        m1[i]=parseInt(document.getElementById('m1').value);
        m2[i]=parseInt(document.getElementById('m2').value);
        m3[i]=parseInt(document.getElementById('m3').value);
        avg[i]=(m1[i]+m2[i]+m3[i])/3;
        total[i]=(m1[i]+m2[i]+m3[i]);
        var mark="Avg="+avg[i]+"<br> Total="+total[i];
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=mark;
        i++;
    }

    function reset()
    {
        name.value = "";
    }


    </script>
    <form name='stud'>
    Enter Name  :<input type='text' name='name' id="name"><br>
    Enter RollNo:<input type='number' name='no' id="rollNum"><br>
    Enter mark 1:<input type='number' name='m1' id='m1'><br>
    Enter mark 2:<input type='number' name='m2' id='m2'><br>
    Enter mark 3:<input type='number' name='m3' id='m3'><br>
    <input type='button' value='calculate' onclick="A()">
    <br>
    <input type='button' value='Enter For Next Student' onclick='reset()'>
    <br><p id='result'></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanx.. But when i'm trying to print like this function print()
     {
         var j;
         for(j=1;j<i;j++)
             document.write(m1[i]+"<br>");
     }

it is showing undefined

Answer (score 0):

Please note that code is sequential. For example you are trying to use input() before you created the function. This is why it's a good idea to either wrap your code in **window.onload=function(){ ... }** or **$( document ).ready(function() { ... }** . That way you don't run into problem in trying to use something before you create it.

Answer (score 0):

This is as Roger stated, certain browsers would rather throw away the whole body content when they encounter document.write.

So if you wish to continue with your code, move all your script inside head and It should work. This way:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var name = new Array(5);
        var roll = new Array(5);
        var m1 = new Array(5);
        var m2 = new Array(5);
        var m3 = new Array(5);
        var total = new Array(5);
        var avg = new Array(5);
        var i = 1;

        function A() {
            m1[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById('m1').value);
            m2[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById('m2').value);
            m3[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById('m3').value);
            avg[i] = (m1[i] + m2[i] + m3[i]) / 3;
            total[i] = (m1[i] + m2[i] + m3[i]);
            var mark = "Avg=" + avg[i] + "<br> Total=" + total[i];
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = mark;
            i++;
        }

        function input() {
            document.write(" <form name='stud'> ");
            document.write(" Enter Name  :<input type='text' name='name'><br>");
            document.write(" Enter RollNo:<input type='number' name='no'><br>");
            document.write(" Enter mark 1:<input type='number' name='m1' id='m1'><br>");
            document.write(" Enter mark 2:<input type='number' name='m2' id='m2'><br>");
            document.write(" Enter mark 3:<input type='number' name='m3' id='m3'><br>");
            document.write("<input type='button' value='calculate' onclick='A();'>");
            document.write(" <br>");
            document.write("<input type='button' value='Enter For Next Student' onclick='input()'>");
            document.write(" <br><p id='1'></p>   ");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="input()"></body>

</html>
```

Comment: This code is showing the same error... Input and A functions are undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `document.write()` completely blows away the entire HTML document, **including the JavaScript** in some browsers.

It works fine in Chrome.

However, in IE, if you view source on your web page, it is this:

```
 <form name='stud'>  Enter Name  :<input type='text' name='name'><br> Enter RollNo:<input type='number' name='no'><br> Enter mark 1:<input type='number' name='m1' id='m1'><br> Enter mark 2:<input type='number' name='m2' id='m2'><br> Enter mark 3:<input type='number' name='m3' id='m3'><br><input type='button' value='calculate' onclick='A();'> <br><input type='button' value='Enter For Next Student' onclick='input()'> <br><p id='1'></p>
```

See any JavaScript?  Nope.  It's gone.

Edit:

Here is the fix (sort of).  The issue is that you need to add the HTML inside the body, not replace the entire document.  This revision adds a  containing the new HTML to the body each time the code is run.

It still has problems, however, which are caused by multiple clicks resulting in elements with duplicate id's.  Id's should be unique within a document.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var name=new Array(5);
            var roll=new Array(5);
            var m1=new Array(5);
            var m2=new Array(5);
            var m3=new Array(5);
            var total=new Array(5);
            var avg=new Array(5);
            var i=1;

            function A() {
                m1[i]=parseInt(document.getElementById('m1').value);
                m2[i]=parseInt(document.getElementById('m2').value);
                m3[i]=parseInt(document.getElementById('m3').value);
                avg[i]=(m1[i]+m2[i]+m3[i])/3;
                total[i]=(m1[i]+m2[i]+m3[i]);
                var mark="Avg="+avg[i]+"<br> Total="+total[i];
                document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=mark;
                i++;
            }             

            function input() {
                var b = "";

                b = "<form name='stud'> ";
                b = b + " Enter Name  :<input type='text' name='name'><br>";
                b = b + " Enter RollNo:<input type='number' name='no'><br>";
                b = b + " Enter mark 1:<input type='number' name='m1' id='m1'><br>";
                b = b + " Enter mark 2:<input type='number' name='m2' id='m2'><br>";
                b = b + " Enter mark 3:<input type='number' name='m3' id='m3'><br>";
                b = b + "<input type='button' value='calculate' onclick='A();'>";
                b = b + " <br>";
                b = b + "<input type='button' value='Enter For Next Student' onclick='input();'>";
                b = b + " <br><p id='1'></p>   ";  

                var div = document.createElement('div');  // Create a <div> to contain the new HTML
                div.innerHTML = b;   // Set the HTML for the <div>
                document.body.appendChild(div);   // Add the new <div> to the body.
            }

            window.onload = input;  // This tells the browser to run input() when the page is done loading.

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, he only asked what the problem was.  I edited my response with a suggested fix.

Comment: i need an answer.. document.body.innerhtml too is not workinh. It shows the same error

Comment: This code is not finding the result for the second student and so on.. It is showing the result of the first student always..

Comment: Right.  As I said in my comments, each time you add a student, the new inputs have the same ids (m1, m2, m3) as the last batch of inputs.  Once there are multiple inputs with the same id, the program doesn't know which one you mean with in the getElementById() call.  You need to redesign it so that each new set of inputs has a unique set of ids.